# Django: getting FIRST item that belongs to a model object in a ManyToManyField

Tags: django, model, many-to-many

Having a model `po` with a `ManyToManyField` called `Order`.

I am considering some options including the following solutions:

```
po.Orders.all()[0].itemname
```

but I am not sure if this solution will be expensive (or not?) basically its querying for the whole table then filter out the first item.

Second solution

```
po.Orders.get(pk=1).itemname
```

This one seem less expensive but doesn't work because its not possible to know the `pk` before hand.

I'm wondering if there are other solutions that will obtain ANY item having the ManyToMany relationship with the `po` object?

Comment: Your first solution is quite optimal. It does a `LIMIT` on the query, and hence quite efficient

Comment: I would suggest using `.first()`. This wasn't a part of Django's ORM two years ago. This should be faster than your first option and do what you were wanting to do in your second option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not true that using `[0]` queries the whole table. As stated in the documentation, slicing a queryset passes a LIMIT/OFFSET to the database query, so this is perfectly efficient.

Answer (score 7):

`.first()` is new in the Django Development version. See the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#first

Until it's out as stable, or you run the dev version, stick with what you have. The QuerySet is lazy, and "should" take the least-work approach. If you're concerned, check your query log in the [MySql General Log](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/query-log.html).

(from the docs)

> Note that first() is a convenience method, the following code sample
>   is equivalent to the above example:
>
> try:
>       p = Article.objects.order_by('title', 'pub_date')[0]
>   except IndexError:
>       p = None